# Summing timeseries data in a python dict

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries in python.`time_data` contains a series of date time objects. `size_data` contains the sizes for the times in the series of date time objects. Both dictionaries have matching `strings` as keys.  The `time_data` contains multiple values for every minute. I want to sum the multiple value for each minute and display it as a single size value. How do I do this?

```
time_data = {}
size_data = {}

//Code to get new size and time `t` and `s`

time_data[match].append(t)
size_data[match].append(s)
```

Sample data values look like below.

```
04:20:54 491
04:21:02 33
04:21:04 1063
04:21:04 1063
04:21:04 711
04:21:09 56
04:21:12 73
04:21:14 1066
04:21:14 931
04:21:18 618
04:21:18 51
04:21:22 27
04:21:24 1063
04:21:24 1063
04:21:24 535
04:21:33 24
04:21:33 1063
04:21:33 1063
04:21:33 978
04:21:43 36
04:21:45 1063
04:21:45 1063
04:21:45 755
04:21:53 27
04:21:55 1066
04:21:55 1063
04:21:55 711
04:22:03 30
04:22:05 1069
04:22:05 1063
04:22:05 1063
04:22:05 450
04:22:10 56
04:22:12 76
04:22:15 1066
04:22:15 1063
04:22:15 1066
```

The values are stored as follows

time_data 
{
 "string1":[04:22:10,04:22,11,04:22,11,04:22,11,04:22:12], 
 "string2":[04:22:10,04:22,11,04:22:13,04:22:13,04:22:13] 
}

size_data 
{
 "string1":[491,33,55,1034,654], 
 "string2":[41,763,1055,104,454] 
}

I just posted the value above as a list.

Comment: can you post any samples?

Comment: @haifzhan - I have added sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Due to your question is not clear, below I use HH:MM:SS as key, if you want to sum up all values for HH:MM, just replace t with t[:5] in the first for loop

$cat test.py

```
time_data = { "string1":["04:22:10","04:22:11","04:22:11","04:22:11","04:22:12"], "string2":["04:22:10","04:22:11","04:22:13","04:22:13","04:22:13"] }

size_data ={ "string1":[491,33,55,1034,654], "string2":[41,763,1055,104,454] }

mydict = dict()

for key in time_data:
    timestamps = time_data.get(key)
    values = size_data.get(key)

    for t, v in zip(timestamps, values):
       mydict.setdefault(t, list()).append(v)


for t, vlist in mydict.items():
    print("key is {0}, value is {1}".format(t, sum(vlist)))
```

$python test.py

```
key is 04:22:10, value is 532
key is 04:22:11, value is 1885
key is 04:22:13, value is 1613
key is 04:22:12, value is 654
```

**Original Answer:**

You can save `hour:minute` as a key, for all values in the same `hour:minute`, store them in a list and sum them up later.

cat sample.csv

```
04:20:23 109
04:21:18 51
04:21:22 27
```

$cat test.py

```
mydict = dict()
with open("sample.csv") as inputs:
    for line in inputs:
        date_time, value = line.strip().split()
        hour_min = date_time[:5]
        mydict.setdefault(hour_min, list()).append(int(value))


for hour_min, vlist in mydict.items():
    print("key:'{0}', value:'{1}'".format(hour_min, sum(vlist)))
```

$python test.py

```
key:'04:21', value:'78'
key:'04:20', value:'109'
```

Comment: I wasn't probably clear initially. Please see update to the question. thanks :)

Comment: the append() method is not being called on the dictionary. It is being called on the list corresponding to each key `match`.

Comment: the `string` is the key and the list of `date time objects`in the dictionary is the value

Comment: I am losing the `key` (string) which was there in the original dictionary. I am using that to plot some graphs.